# C++ unique_ptr acts like it's copying the value

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

In this code:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 11;
    int* rawPointer = &x;
    unique_ptr<int> integerPointer = make_unique<int>(x);
    cout << *rawPointer << std::endl;
    x++;
    cout << *rawPointer << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

when we ask for the value of `rawPointer`, the output is :

```
11
12
```

which is correct. But when we ask for the value of `integerPointer`, which happens to be a unique `pointer`, we get the output :

```
11
11
```

I would have thought that it would behave just like `rawPointer`. Why is that? Is that really the way unique `pointers` work?

Thanks

Comment: `make_unique` creates a new object (with the initial value of `x`), it doesn't "take over" `x`

Comment: If you do `make_unique(11)`, would you expect that pointer to control constant?

Comment: @Slava I was expecting it to behave just like raw pointers where it would "point" to the address (or value), except it would go out of scope and delete itself; I didn't expect it to make a copy of the value.

Comment: @chelem7 it does point, just `make_unique` does something that you do not expect. `make_unique<int>(x)` is logically equal to `unique_ptr( new int(x) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [std::unique_ptr reference docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique):

> Constructs an object of type T and wraps it in a std::unique_ptr.

So you're constructing a new copy, managed by the `unique_ptr` by passing `x`, and not managing `x` by address.